# Автозапуск видео IFrame в Yandex Browser и Chrome

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api

Поместил видео с YouTube в теле сайта, используя IFrame API. Есть ли возможность обойти блокировку автозапуска со звуком видео в браузере Yandex Browser и Chrome?

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId:'',
        playerVars: {controls:0, showinfo:0, rel:0, disablekb:1,cc_load_policy:0,fs:0,iv_load_policy:3},
        events: {
            'onReady': readyPlayer
        }
    });
}

function readyPlayer(e){
    e.target.loadVideoById({
        videoId:'SbQc_JLUH7k',
        startSeconds:0
    });
    e.target.playVideo();
}
```

Comment: напишите код, который вы уже пытались использовать

Comment: @sterx исправил вопрос